# Invalid object name 'dbo.AspNetUsers' in MVC5 site with Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, shared-hosting

Everything works great on my local machine where the database owner is 'dbo'.  But then I deploy it to a shared hosting site who won't let us use 'dbo'. Instead the table owner is the sql server user who I connect as.  We'll call him 'sheldoncooper'.  So all my tables are sheldoncooper.AspNetUsers, sheldoncooper.AspNetRoles, sheldoncooper.AspNetUserClaims, and so on.

It looks like the Identity system is looking for a hardcoded dbo.AspNetUsers, dbo.AspNetRoles, etc.

How do I tell it to NOT key on dbo?

[Edit] NVM, This is definitely a dup.

Comment: It's not hard coded, it's just default.

Answer (score 0):

You can either specify per table the schema to use, but in your case it's probably easier to globally change it by overriding the OnModelCreating method like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // You can globally assign schema here
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("sheldoncooper");
}
```